# Permission error running Google Vertex example

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-aiplatform

I'm trying to run the Bison examples on their [website](https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative/language/create/chat) as well as Python in colab and I'm facing the same error. When initially started this I was prompted to enable services, which I did, but it's still not working. Since this is my personal test I'm logged in as Owner.

```
ERROR. Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/cloud-ai-frontend/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/chat-bison@001' (or it may not exist).
```

In Collab the error is as following:

```
PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/cloud-ai-frontend/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/chat-bison@001' (or it may not exist). [reason: "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
domain: "aiplatform.googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "permission"
  value: "aiplatform.endpoints.predict"
}
metadata {
  key: "resource"
  value: "projects/cloud-ai-frontend/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/chat-bison@001"
}
]
```

Update 1: I used the policy troubleshooter, entered my Gmail address, resource1 being //aiplatform.googleapis.com/.../chat-bison@001 (as above) and permission 1 aiplatform.endpoints.predict it tells me
"You do not have the required permissions to troubleshoot policies on the specified resource"

Update 2: I created a new project and it's working fine now, but I'm still bugged by the fact that the other project doesn't work

Comment: The service account you're using is missing the permission `aiplatform.endpoints.predict`. Add it and try again afterwards.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I'm logged in as owner, not a service account, is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: owner doesnt have necessarily all permissions, try adding the role/permission explicitly anyway (?)

Comment: how should I add permission to service account? Can't find in CLoud Console unfortunately...

Comment: Even with "AI platform admin" access to a service account, I get `Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied`.

Comment: update: it takes a few minutes for IAM permissions to take effect. It's working after I waited for 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

I tested and it works normally.

You can try following this notebook I tested.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1m2FrsUPlazVx2BZUdxKKJ_3FFDTRohar